# Fluid geometry not flowing when baked inside of domain

Tags: fluid-simulation, cache

My goal was to have the head turn into fluid and fall down onto the floor of the domain. I have done a little with fluid sims in the past. I'll try to describe everything I did, but I think downloading the blend file will make the problem/solution clearer. I started by making a cube around the head, then designating it the domain. I then took the head(split into 2 parts from a previous animation, with the bowtie being the 3rd part) and designated all parts as a geometry. After baking the fluid, I played the animation, and it didn't flow. The domain cube didn't even disappear like it usually does. I made sure that mesh was checked in the domain, set viscosity to 0, looked inside the head to see if it was full of liquid, and there was nothing. I then set the initial velocity to see if the fluid would render, rebaked it, and got nothing again. I made sure the resolution and sampling steps were high, baked it, and still got nothing.

Why isn't the head-shaped fluid showing up or flowing and why is the domain not even disappearing? Do you think it's a cache issue?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your inflow object (head) is not closed/manifold. Close it with faces. You can retruy it yourself. Insert a simple UV Sphere, make it inflow -> works. Insert another simple UV Sphere. Delete some faces. Make it inflow -> does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your head is open at the top. To generate fluid particles Mantaflow needs:

either a closed mesh so that it can create the particles inside the volume

or

if you want keep an open mesh to generate particles, you have to enable the option *Is Planar* on the flow object, i.e. the head.

[image: is_planar_option]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks so much! I tried that, then today kind of out of the blue the fluid appeared when I opened blender. It works now